# Save build result to mavenLocal in Android Studio / gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, android-studio

In Android Studio, when I select Tools -> Google Cloud Tools -> Install Client Libraries, Google generates an endpoint library and stores it in my local Maven repository. In gradle, this is probably done using a plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'appengine'

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

Now, I can use the library in another project:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal() // Reference the local Maven repository to access the backend
}

dependencies {
    compile 'cc.closeup.backend:api:v1-1.18.0-rc-SNAPSHOT' // Dependency to the generated library
}
```

Is there a way to do this with one of my regularly built jars? In other words: How do I need to configure gradle to place built jars into the local repository each time the project compiles. [I know this can be done using a mvn command, but I want to execute this every time the project compiles, and I couldn't find anything about it on the web.]

Where I want to go: I have two projects, and I am developing both at the same time, and I want to ensure that the second project always gets the latest libraries from the first one, without manually shuffling files around. [I know I could make a single project, but I there are reasons why the projects need to stay separate.]

I have tried using

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishToMavenLocal()
```

according to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html but it doesn't work for me somehow. There is no sample on the website and I don't know enough about gradle to "guess" how to apply the command.

Comment: I saw somebody has starred this question. I asked this a second time differently as I did not get results and it has been answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233518/use-gradle-to-upload-jar-to-local-maven-repository