# Use gradle to upload jar to local Maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, android-studio

This question has been asked several times, but somehow I don't get this to work. Gradle is a great tool, but its documentation is anything but great. No examples make it almost impossible to understand for someone who doesn't use it on a daily basis.

I am using Android Studio and I want to upload my module output jar to my local Maven repository.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
}


apply plugin: 'maven'
configure(install.repositories.mavenInstaller) {
    pom.project {
        groupId 'com.example'
        artifactId 'example'
        packaging 'jar'
    }
}
```

When I start a build in Android Studio, I can see on the Gradle tab that

```
:install
```

is invoked. I also get a new jar in my build folder, but that jar is not uploaded to Maven. [The Maven repo exists and the Google appengine gradle plugin uploads its jar from another module of the same project just fine.]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to install into the local Maven repository? How exactly do you tell that it isn't working?

Comment: Which path do you take as 'local maven repository'? Just making sure we're on the same page here..

Comment: @Peter Niederwieser Yes, I want to install into my local Maven repository, because I have several projects and the output of one is used as input for another, and I need a quick fix to get the libraries exchanged on my local machine. We are planning to use a privately hosted repository later. The setup is completely different for local and remote repos, right? Is that why you're asking?

Comment: @gerrytan The path is my local user directory and then .m2 and it is properly set up in my Windows environment, as I can use mavenLocal() to pull repos from there.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Gradle but I'm guessing the reason documentation is thin is because it's based on Maven. Try go though [doco for maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/). With plain maven I normally just need to run the `install` goal to make sure my artifact gets deployed to local repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are only editing the POM (via `pom.project`), instead of configuring the actual Maven coordinates used for installation. Try the following instead:

```
// best way to set group ID
group = 'com.example'

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // only necessary if artifact ID diverges from project name
        // the latter defaults to project directory name and can be
        // configured in settings.gradle
        pom.artifactId = 'myName' 
        // shouldn't be needed as this is the default anyway
        pom.packaging = 'jar'
    }
}
```

PS: The `samples` directory in the full Gradle distribution contains many example builds, also for the `maven` plugin.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Niederwieser, this solved my problem. I added pom.version = "v1-1.0-SNAPSHOT" as the version was generated as "undefined". Not sure if this is the correct way of doing this or if it can be derived from the Android Studio project/module somehow, but it works now.

Comment: Best way is to set `version`, similar to how you set `group`.

Comment: I got error:  Gradle DSL method not found :'install()' , I am using Gradle 2.1 .

Comment: Likely means you didn't apply the `maven` plugin.

Comment: Just to clarify: the upload will be performed when executing `gradle install`

Comment: This doesn't work with gradle 7.x. How do we go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Peter N is CORRECT in the comments of the accepted answer, which works, but shouldn't be the accepted answer.

You should have this in your `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: "maven"
```

Then you can just do a

```
$ ./gradlew install
```

Or use the built-in task

```
$ ./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

Both methods install the artifacts in `$HOME/.m2/com/example/example/version`