# Install project built jar to local maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am trying to install my project built jar to my local maven repository. I am using **Gradle 2.1** with Android Studio IDE. I found the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233518/use-gradle-to-upload-jar-to-local-maven-repository), but it doesn't work for me. Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'android'
...

group 'com.my.app'
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.artifactId = 'MyApp'
        pom.packaging = 'jar'
    }
}
```

When I do gradle build, I got error message:

`Gradle DSL method not found :'install()'`

Why my Gradle can not recognize `install()` method? How to install project jar to local maven repository then?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#uploading_to_maven_repositories) are the docs You're looking for.

And here's the relevant piece of code:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://localhost/tmp/myRepo/")
        }
    }
}
```